# Function which operates on subset of properties that extend some type

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function which takes an object `T` and a property key which is `keyof T`, but further constrained such that the property must extend some other type, for example `Date`.

(I'll use the date type going forward, but it's really just an example.)

I can derive a type that picks out such properties using:

```js
type Dates<T> = {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends Date | undefined ? P : never]: T[P]
};
```

But my attempts to write a function that's correctly typed which acts on this subset of properties have failed.

```js
function doSomething<T>(inst: T, key: keyof T) {
    const date = inst[key];
    //    ^ But must be constrained to the `Date | undefined` type.
}
```

Comment: You're looking for what I call `KeysMatching<T, V>`, but there is no *native* support for this, as requested in [ms/TS#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992). Right now any method to have the compiler understand inside `doSomething()` that `date` is a subtype of `Date | undefined` (right? you put `undefined` in there) will make the function generic in the type of `key`. Two methods are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2g24N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This seems to work very nicely! But I don't see how `& { [k: string]: any }` is necessary in the second example. It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: It avoids excess property warnings, similar to how `T extends Record<K, Date | undefined>` does.; if you do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOKllw) and remove `& {[k: string]: any}`, you'll see the issue.

Comment: Must be because that object is created without an interface – see [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1Gnkm) example.

Comment: Excess property checking happens in specific circumstances. It's not the interface per se that's the issue, but the fact you're passing in `a` instead of an object literal. Is this part of the discussion relevant enough to the question to warrant changing something about the suggested answer? I'm thinking this is mostly a digression. Assuming I write up an answer I would of course explain why the code has the form it does. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes definitely and thank you very much!

Comment: I've decided just to avoid that entirely by keeping it generic in `T` and not introducing a second generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, given your `Dates` definition, you'd write this:

```
function doSomething<T>(inst: T, key: keyof Dates<T>) {
   const date = inst[key];
   date?.getdate(); // error
}
```

But unfortunately TypeScript can't "see" that `inst[key]` is of a type assignable to `Date | undefined`, for generic `inst`, even though this is implied by the definition of `Dates`.  TypeScript lacks a native operator of the form "the properties of `T` assignable to type `V`". I usually call this `KeysMatching<T, V>`, where `KeysMatching<T, Date | undefined>` is like `keyof Dates<T>` for your code.  You can, of course, define your own version that works in some circumstances, but when `T` is generic the compiler can't follow the logic. There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) to support `KeysMatching` natively, but for now it's not part of the language and you'll need to work around it.

---

The minimal workaround I can envision is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to itself in such a way so that TypeScript knows that `T[keyof Dates<T>]` is a subtype of `Date | undefined`. Like this, for example:

```
function doSomething<
   T extends Record<keyof Dates<T>, Date | undefined>,
>(inst: T, key: keyof Dates<T>) {
   const date = inst[key];
   date?.getDate() // okay
}
```

That works as advertised. Let's test it:

```
const v = { a: "abc", b: new Date(), c: undefined, d: 123 };    
doSomething(v, "b"); // okay
doSomething(v, "c"); // okay
doSomething(v, "a"); // error! 
// Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b" | "c"'
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCBnAPAFQHxQLxQN4BQUxA2gApQCWAdlANYQgD2AZlGlHEu+QLpQQAHomoATbvERQAPlACuYiCxoRRUAPxQKALijUIANwgAnXrrR8CAXwDcBAiwUBjYJSa1RTAMpMAthGAACxoAcwAGdAwAChokYHMAGnpGXQZmNklkSIBKfCJiJ3c4qFEEaFxY4BI03jtiErL1ADoQgNLEKOybKAB6HoFjYyZja3tHahc3D28-AODqEJR89gFhCDFuACUIQuNRFDTWWDLUTCTMmXlFZX1RDASCaMrE5JBUxiPM04xcwnrC6jFdrlKiAqo1OrEYHNVrATKdXr9Jh0OAgUYEAHFAw4fCcXQAIjgACMnPikkTdPoAO7HDrZJJOXQKURKFSiJKiXQARgATABmKC2eyeHz+IKhKIGJL4on4rqIqDI1EEEWzcULSXS0nyvqKlFo1Vi+YhTVQQly7q6kxDYwAQigAEFjCE5P5qMBFWxQJAoAByc2+qjcahMD1cJCUELUYkAG2gwCYUDAcGMcDFJk9UG90H9ssu+NJvvsBCAA)